# UINavigationBar with extra black bar in iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I have an old project in `Objective-C` which required to update to support `iPhone X`. Even after updating with the recommended update suggested by the `xCode 9.1` I am getting an extra black bar within `UINavigationBar`.
I have tried to use `Safe area layout` but no effective result found. The problem still not solved. I have attached some screenshots to explain the issue. Please help me to get out of this issue. Thank you.
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and down vote. Can you please explain me the reason why this issue happened or the reason for the downvote. I appreciate your time and efforts for the reply.

Comment: post code how you added navigation bar and use debug view hierarchy to find the issue what is the reason for black bar . In mean time check in code are you adding any view with black color

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not adding any code to customise the navigation bar nor adding any view in the same. I am sorry but due to some restrictions I can not share the code.

Comment: try to use https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html  to find what is the reason for black view

Comment: @Vinodh Thank you for your time and reply and help. I found my solution by debugging using the method explained in the link you have provided. It was my mistake, I am adding a black view in status bar with height = height of status bar. Please add your comment as an answer so that I can make it as the accepted answer.

Comment: you are most welcome . even on last comment i told the same check . Please post it as a answer so others will know what fixed your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help and suggestion of Mr. Vinodh above in the comment, I tried to evaluate the screen bu debugging using the method explained in the link shared by Mr. Vinodh. The link he shared above is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html 
By visiting the link and debugging through the method explained here I come to know that I am adding a black view in status bar programmatically.
The method explains the way to debug the **view hierarchy**. The hierarchical view of the Image attached above in my question is as
 [image]